# Is there an execute-store data hazard in MIPS?

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

On MIPS architecture with pipelining and forwarding:

```
add $s0, $t1, $t2
sw $s0, 0($sp)
```

The add instruction will have the result ready at step 3 (execute operation) however I presume that the sw instruction want the result at step 2 (Instruction decode & register read).

There is a solved exercise in the book Computer Organization and Design by David A. Patterson: *Find the hazards in the following code segment and reorder the instructions to avoid any pipeline stalls*:

```
lw  $t1, 0($t0)
lw  $t2, 4($t0)
add $t3, $t1,$t2
sw  $t3, 12($t0)
lw  $t4, 8($01)
add $t5, $t1,$t4
sw  $t5, 16($t0)
```

Solution:

```
lw  $t1, 0($t0)
lw  $t2, 4($t1)
lw  $t4, 8($01)
add $t3, $t1,$t2
sw  $t3, 12($t0)
add $t5, $t1,$t4
sw  $t5, 16($t0)
```

In the solution it correctly recognizes the load-use hazard and rearranges the code accordingly, but is there an execute-store hazard as well?

Comment: The load-use hazard comes from loads taking two cycles while other simple instructions (excluding, e.g., multiply) take only one cycle. The result from a simple instruction can be forwarded to the execution stage of the next instruction, so even for a base address register value there is no hazard (e.g., `add $t2, $t2, 1; sw $t4, 0($t2)`). For a store, since address generation, cache indexing, and tag check must be done before the store data is actually written even longer latency could be tolerated; the store data might not even be needed until the writeback stage of the store instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a MIPS in which forwarding is activated.
I think that in that case no hazard occurs: in fact the ADD instruction is an integer operation that in the MIPS architecture requires only one clock cycle.
Look at this graph:

```
ADD $t3,$t1,$t2    IF   ID   EX   MEM   WB
SW  $t3,12($t0)         IF   ID   EX    MEM  WB
```

As you can see no hazard occurs because the SW instruction stores the datum after two clock cycles since the result is put in $t3 by ADD.

Actually in similar situations a hazard can occur but only if the unit is a multicycle one (if it requires  more than one clock cycle to compute the data).
Look ad this example, in which the ADD.D instruction uses a floating point adder that requires 4 clock cycles to perform the calculation:

```
ADD.D F2,F4,F5      IF   ID   A0   A1   A2   A3   MEM   WB
S.D   F2,somewhere       IF   ID   EX   X0   X1   X2    MEM    WB
```

X0 and X1 are RAW stalls while X2 is a structural stalls: in the former case S.D must wait for ADD.D to finish; in the latter your MIPS cannot access in the same clock cycle to the memory two times, so a structural stall occurs.

Comment: So for your second example, the solution would be to put some other instruction in between them that doesn't use those registers?